# Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am beginner in javascript.

**js file**

```
         var msgErrorPalletizedWeight = document.getElementById('msgError');
         function palletizedWeightValidation() {
              console.log("hello");
/*ERROR*/     msgErrorPalletizedWeight.innerHTML += ("Please enter all the values marked with *");
         }
```

**HTML**

```
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="Scripts/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="msgError"></p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitPalletized" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                   OnClientClick="palletizedWeightValidation()" />
</body>
```

ERROR

> Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

I searched many sites before asking here, they all recommending to check for null before validations which I can do but my problem here is I want to add some text to the `p` tag as you can see.. How to achieve that? I even tried appending, thought it might solve the problem. I know this is a silly mistake because there are many posts on this... the thing is that I cant understand where I am going wrong.

Please help.

Comment: Hey, if it is silly mistake, answer in comments.. please.

Comment: You probably run the code *before* the element is available. Move the JavaScript code just before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: How do you run this JS code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are `trying` to access the `element` of html when it is not `ready`, put the statement in event function to get the element in function `palletizedWeightValidation`.

```
      function palletizedWeightValidation() {
              var msgErrorPalletizedWeight = document.getElementById('msgError');
              console.log("hello");
/*ERROR*/     msgErrorPalletizedWeight.innerHTML += ("Please enter all the values marked ith *");
         }
```

**EDIT** *To stop postback*, you need to return false from javascrip function.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitPalletized" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                   OnClientClick="return palletizedWeightValidation()" />


      function palletizedWeightValidation() {
              var msgErrorPalletizedWeight = document.getElementById('msgError');
              console.log("hello");
/*ERROR*/     msgErrorPalletizedWeight.innerHTML += ("Please enter all the values marked ith *");
              return false; // returning true will cause postback.
         }
```

Comment: Thanks it is working.. but I dont know why the message is only visible for very short time.. any idea why?

Comment: You need to check if any javascript is setting text to empty or hidding the msgErrorPalletizedWeight

Comment: I realized now that button is going to server side whenever I clicked it..(refreshing my page) which is making my javascript code to show up for very short time. Any way to stop the button to go to server?

Comment: You can return false, OnClientClick="palletizedWeightValidation(); return false;" or OnClientClick="return palletizedWeightValidation()" and return false from palletizedWeightValidation body.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is when your js file gets executed.
If you load js file inside head tag, your file will be executed before DOM is created. That means, document.getElementById function returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is caused because you are trying to read an attribute of a NULL object. This means that your line:

```
var msgErrorPalletizedWeight = document.getElementById('msgError');
```

is not finding any elements on your page.